# Call MethodByName in array of struct: panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value

Tags: go, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to make a dynamic function call of each element of an array:

```
var EsPersonList []EsEntry

func (this *EsEntry) FullName() string {
    return this.Wholename
}

func createStr(d interface{}) {
    items := reflect.ValueOf(d)

    if items.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < items.Len(); i++ {
            item := items.Index(i)
            if item.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                v := reflect.ValueOf(&item)
                return_values := v.MethodByName("FullName").Call([]reflect.Value{})
                fmt.Println(return_values)
            }
        }
    }
}

createStr(EsPersonList)
```

I get is a panic that looks like this:
`panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value`

https://play.golang.org/p/vK2hUfVcMwr

How can I fix this?

Comment: you have to call `MethodByName` on `item`, not on `v`

Comment: return_values := item.MethodByName("FullName").Call([]reflect.Value{})
Not working. Same error

Comment: `item` is a `reflect.Value`. `&item` is a `*reflect.Value`. `reflect.ValueOf(&item)` is the reflection of a pointer to a reflection and not what you want.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/l4wIXQ1Vyyb use `item.Addr()` instead of `reflect.ValueOf(&item)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [comment by mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188975/call-methodbyname-in-array-of-struct-panic-reflect-call-of-reflect-value-call#comment120515356_68188975), use `item.Addr()` to get address of the field, not `reflect.ValueOf(&item)`.  The latter gets the reflect value of a reflect value.  The method call fails because reflect.Value does not have the method FullName.